# Error in a MVC application with ASP.NET when I try to populate a table

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm a begginer in asp.net , mvc.I try to populate a table and I receive this error :

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'K_Api.Notification' because 'K_Api.Notification' does not contain a
>   public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

I have a Controller and here I call my view with one parameter.This parameter is a list with data that I want to find in my grid(3 columns: from,subject,status;In my list I have 3 rows).

This is the definition for my list :

```
 List<Notification> sNotificationList=new List<Notification>(); //Notification is a class with the 3 columns and their types
```

and this is the call to my view :

```
return View("NotificationsList", sNotificationList);
```

In notificationList.aspx first row is:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Child.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<K_Api.Notification>" %>
```

Then I have :

```
      <%        
      foreach (K_Api.Notification s in Model)
        {
       %>
    <tr>
      <td> <%= Model.From %></td>
      <td> <%= Model.Status %></td>
      <td> <%= Model.Subject%></td>
   </tr> 
       <%        
     }%>
```

Can somebody please tell me where is the error?

Comment: Please add the definition of K_Api.Notification. You define the Model to be of type K_Api.Notification (look at the end of <%Page %> statement). So you cannot iterate over Model and expect every item to be an K_Api.Notification instance. Or?

Comment: those `<%= Model.From %>` etc. should probably be `<%= s.From %>` because otherwise I don't see a reason why would anyone enumerate through model objects...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model definition in the view is wrong. You need your model to be an `IEnumerable<K_Api.Notification>` if you want to be able to loop through it. So modify your view in order to be conform to the type you are passing from the controller action:

```
<%@ Page 
    Title="" 
    Language="C#"     
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Child.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<K_Api.Notification>>" 
%>
```

This obviously supposes that your controller action passes an `IEnumerable<Notification>` to this view:

```
public ActionResult NotificationsList()
{
    IEnumerable<Notification> model = new List<Notification>();
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.After I changed what Darin  tell me  it was ok.And Robert you was right , but I changed for so many times and I try a lot of things and I forget model in place of s. Thanks a lot !